# Json-Server Delete, Update on Nested Object

Tags: javascript, api, put, json-server

I have an example employee object,

```js
  "employees": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "address": "Lorem Ipsum is simply...",
      "name": "fat",
      "surname": "sum",
      "trainings": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "training_name": "ddsadsa",
          "training_desc": "ewwe",
          "start_date": "15.06.2021",
          "end_date": "17.06.2021",
          "training_certification": "CRM Certified"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "training_name": "aaasd",
          "training_desc": "3334",
          "start_date": "21.07.2022",
          "end_date": "-",
          "training_certification": ""
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "address": "Lorem Ipsum is simply...",
      "name": "teve",
      "surname": "Thes",
      "trainings": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "training_name": "ddsadsa",
          "training_desc": "ewwe",
          "start_date": "15.06.2021",
          "end_date": "17.06.2021",
          "training_certification": "CRM Certified"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "training_name": "aaasd",
          "training_desc": "3334",
          "start_date": "21.07.2022",
          "end_date": "-",
          "training_certification": ""
        },
      ]
    },
  ],
```

I want to update or delete the items in the trainings object of each employee, I tried _embed in json-server like this but it didn't work:

```js
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/employees/1?_embed=trainings/2
Request Method: DELETE
Status Code: 404 Not Found
```

(So, delete id:2 training item of id:1 employee item)

Thanks for helps,

Comment: I think the URL should be `http://localhost:3000/employees/1/trainings/2` you don't have relationships in your data.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is also not worked,

Comment: Do you habe nested objects or relationships? I've read that nested objects with 1 level depth support GET and POST requests. I don't know whether they support other requests. Perhaps it's not possible and you have to restructure your data or use routes.